# I can't get Pokemon go?

Tags: pokemon-go

I live in the Midwestern portion of the US, I have a Motorola Droid With Android version 4.4.4 (Kitkat), and everywhere I read it tells me I should be able to download Pokemon Go, but it doesn't allow me to do so.

Note that I do not want to download the APK and risk getting malware or getting banned from getting the game.

Does anybody know why I can't get Pokemon go yet?

Comment: Is it not in the Play store, or is your Play store account from a different country?

Comment: It's not showing up in my phones play store, and if I try to download it remotely (from my PC or Kindle) it tells me that the app is not compatible with my device. I am fairly sure that my Play store account is from the US, but is there a way for me to check?

Comment: @Kirklandish On a PC, when you need to select your device, under devices name, it should tell you a reason why it's incompatible.

Comment: @gre_gor All it says for me is "No carrier Motorola" "this item is not compatible with your device."

Comment: To me it's shown like [this](http://i.imgur.com/OPevJNQ.png)

Comment: This is what it's showing me http://imgur.com/cg0ePPH

Comment: Someone could send you a clean apk from google play, its a free game at all. post the apk manifest on stackoverflow and they will tell you why your device cannot download it.

Comment: From what I heard, if you are caught with an APK you could be banned from ever getting the game.

Comment: Any chance your Motorola has an Intel chip? The [supported devices](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/221958248-Supported-devices) page notes that devices with Intel CPUs aren't supported.

Comment: @pushasha I might, how can I figure out what my phones CPU is?

Comment: @pushasha Nevermind! I do not have a Intel CPU, thank you though.

Answer (score 4):

I found the problem! My phone only has 1GB of RAM, but according to the notes Google play it needs 2. Luckily, I am getting a new phone later this month. Thank you to everyone who tried to help.